# Find the probability $\mathbb{P}(\min( X_{1},\ldots,X_{n})=X_{1})$ where $X_i$'s are independent

Tags: probability, independence

If $X_{1}, X_{2},\ldots, X_{n}$ be *i.i.d* random variables, what is the probability $$\mathbb{P}(\min( X_{1}, X_{2},\ldots,X_{n})=X_{1})\,?$$

Because every $X_{i}$ is equally likely to be the smallest one,

$$\mathbb{P}(\min( X_{1}, X_{2},\ldots,X_{n})=X_{1})=\frac1n$$

And my question is, if $X_{1}, X_{2},\ldots, X_{n}$ be *independent* random variables.

For example, the distribution of $X_{i}$ is exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda_{i}>0$.  What is the probability $\mathbb{P}(\min( X_{1}, X_{2},\ldots,X_{n})=X_{1})$ ?

Comment: Still 1/n ? I think they are independent ,so equal chance to be smallest  ????

Comment: $X_i$ with the largest $\lambda_i$ would have the highest probability of being the smallest.  Calculation looks difficult.

Comment: @CharlieF they may be independent but they have different distributions, so you can't immediately conclude that it's $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @clement-yung You are right.

Comment: @herb-steinberg Yes,  and robert-israel have given an answer I think is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part, the answer is $1/n$ if $X_i$  are continuous random variables.  If they are discrete, the probability is greater than $1/n$ because there is nonzero probability that more than one $X_i$ is the minimum.

In the second part, the answer will obviously depend on the distributions of the $X_i$.  If $X_i$ has density $f_i(x)$,
$$ \mathbb P(\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=X_1) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_1 \int_{x_1}^\infty dx_2 \ldots \int_{x_1}^\infty dx_n\; f(x_1)\ldots f(x_n) $$
In your exponential example (where $\lambda_i$ are rate parameters), this is 
$$ \int_0^\infty dx_1 \lambda_1 e^{-(\lambda_1+\ldots +\lambda_n) x_1}= \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_n}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I understand.